# Reading multiple files in R as string in a for.loop

Tags: r, csv, lapply

I have a code that reads two different csv files from a folder at the time of execution. i need to use for loop in this context to execute this multiple times and write the output in to a separate csv file of the form "bsc_.csv". The file format of the two input csv files are "base_.csv" and "fut_.csv".  The files are incrementally numbered, and that that is the pattern I need to iterative over. The sample code is attached below.

```
library('CDFt')
d1<-read.csv("base1.csv",header=TRUE)
d2<-read.csv("fut1.csv",header=TRUE)
A1<-d1[,2]
A2<-d1[,3]
A3<-d2[,2]
CT<-CDFt(A1,A2,A3)
x<-CT$x
FGp<-CT$FGp
FGf<-CT$FGf
FRp<-CT$FRp
FRf<-CT$FRf
ds<-CT$DS
d<-round(ds,3)
dat<-replace(d,d<0,0)
write.table(dat,"bsc1.csv", row.names=F,na="NA",append=T, quote= FALSE, sep=",", col.names=F)
```

Comment: Where's the problem? If you are receiving errors, it would help to see the verbatim text of those errors (or warnings or whatever). If the output is error-free but still not correct, we still need info.

Comment: As a beginner I am not sure how to use for loop in this code.

Comment: Nothing you've presented is loopable. Do you need to loop over different directories?

Comment: In a directory, I have csv files of name base1.csv, base2.csv, base3.csv, fut1.csv, fut2.csv, fut3.csv. While executing the code, it reads base1.csv and fut1.csv as mentioned in the sample code and writes the output as bsc1.csv. I want to create a for loop to execute this code two more times upon reading base2.csv, fut2.csv, and base3.csv,  fut3.csv files. Please gelp me how to proceed.

Comment: You really should edit your question. While your *code* does include `fut1.csv`, you never mention the fact that the files are incrementally numbered, and that that is the pattern you need to iterative over.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now this code is working perfectly.

Comment: The only issue is that the output vector is getting mixed with the row index number.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, but is that a problem with the looping (this question) or with the process in general (new question)? I don't know that we can do much without sample input data, actual output, and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```r
bases <- list.files(pattern = "base[0-9]*\\.csv$")
futs <- list.files(pattern = "fut[0-9]*\\.csv$")

mismatches <- setdiff(gsub("^base", "", bases), gsub("^fut", "", futs) )
if (length(mismatches)) {
  warning("'bases' files not in 'futs': ", paste(sQuote(mismatches), collapse = ", "))
  bases <- setdiff(bases, paste0("base", mismatches))
}
# and the reverse
mismatches <- setdiff(gsub("^fut", "", futs), gsub("^base", "", bases) )
if (length(mismatches)) {
  warning("'futs' files not in 'bases': ", paste(sQuote(mismatches), collapse = ", "))
  futs <- setdiff(futs, paste0("fut", mismatches))
}

ign <- Map(function(fb, ff) {
  bdat <- read.csv(fb, header = TRUE)
  fdat <- read.csv(ff, header = TRUE)
  # ...
  newfn <- gsub("^base", "bsc", fb)
  write.table(dat, newfn, ...)
}, bases, futs)
```